# How to persist data on many side of relationship with composite primary keys on many side of relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am stuck with a problem and any help would be highly appreciated.
I have a one to may relationship entities with mostly having composite primary keys on many side of relationship.
e.g I have two entities like `Client` and `Client_User` and `Client` is associated with `Client_User` which is having composite primary key i-e, `client_id` and `user_id`, I want to persist data to `Client_User` Entity when I am persisting data to `Client` Entity using Spring data Jpa. My entities are written as below:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class ClientEntity implements Serializable {
   private int clientId;
   private int userId;
   private Collection<ClientUserEntity> clientUsersByClientId;

   // ...
   
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clientByClientId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
   public Collection<ClientUserEntity> getClientUsersByClientId() {
        return clientUsersByClientId;
   }
   public void setClientUsersByClientId(Collection<ClientUserEntity> clientUsersByClientId) {
        this.clientUsersByClientId = clientUsersByClientId;
   }
}
    
@Entity
@Table(name = "client_user")
@IdClass(ClientUserEntityPK.class)
public class ClientUserEntity implements Serializable {
   private int clientId;
   private int userId;
        
   @Id
   @Column(name = "client_id")
   public int getClientId() {
       return clientId;
   }
   public void setClientId(int clientId) {
       this.clientId = clientId;
   }
        
   @Id
   @Column(name = "user_id")
   public int getUserId() {
      return userId;
   }
   public void setUserId(int userId) {
      this.userId = userId;
   }
  
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "client_id", nullable = false,insertable =false ,updatable  =false)
   public ClientEntity getClientByClientId() {
      return clientByClientId;
   }
   public void setClientByClientId(ClientEntity clientByClientId) {
      this.clientByClientId = clientByClientId;
   }
}
        
public class ClientUserEntityPK implements Serializable {
   private int clientId;
   private int userId;
    
   @Column(name = "client_id")
   @Id
   public int getClientId() {
      return clientId;
   }
   public void setClientId(int clientId) {
      this.clientId = clientId;
   }
    
   @Column(name = "user_id")
   @Id
   public int getUserId() {
       return userId;
   }
   public void setUserId(int userId) {
       this.userId = userId;
   }
    
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
       ClientUserEntityPK that = (ClientUserEntityPK) o;
       return clientId == that.clientId &&
              userId == that.userId;
   }
    
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hash(clientId, userId);
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you everyone , i solved this problem . if anyone else is facing same issue kindly comment so that i would write the detailed solution.